# Can ZeroMQ (NetMQ) TCP transport be used between publisher and subscriber in the same process?

Tags: c#, .net, zeromq, netmq

I think that the question says it all really.

For a bit of background, I have a subscriber that I am trying to write some tests for.  In order to do that, I spin up a publisher from within the test specifying `tcp://localhost:[port]` as the address.  When a message is sent, the subscriber doesn't receive it.  Here is some sample code to demonstrate:

```
   string address   =    "tcp://localhost:1026";
// string address   = "inproc://localhost1026";

   var    pubSocket =  new PublisherSocket();
   pubSocket.Bind(address);

   var subSocket = new SubscriberSocket();
   subSocket.Connect(address);
   subSocket.SubscribeToAnyTopic();

   pubSocket.SendFrame("Hello world!", false);

   Console.WriteLine(subSocket.ReceiveFrameString()); /* <-- tcp transport 
                                                         waits here forever
                                                         */
   subSocket.Dispose();
   pubSocket.Dispose();
```

If I change the protocol to `inproc://` then all is well.  I don't want to do this in my tests, however, because I also want to test a monitor socket and this doesn't raise events for **`inproc://`** connections (as far as I can see).

Note that I am using NetMQ from C# code (running under .NET Framework 4.6.2).

Answer (score 3):

> *Can ZeroMQ (NetMQ) TCP transport be used between publisher and subscriber in the same process ?*

### Absolutely,
there is no restriction preventing one from doing this, yet . . .

Your observation is related to the latency of the hidden processing, that takes place inside the main engine ... inside the ZeroMQ **`Context()`** instance.

**Things do not happen in zero-time**.

Well, one may opt to postpone this one right after the Pieter HINTJENS' one, the "**Code Connected, Volume 1**" on ZeroMQ **Zen-of-Zero**. That both make sense, a lot of sense, not only here ).

So, while the **`inproc://`** transport-class has *(almost)*-zero-resources, being a pure private-"in-process" memory-mapped abstraction ( sure, except perhaps a few **sub-`[ns]`**-"devices" like a semaphore/lock ), the ZeroMQ infrastructure gets up and running in an "immediate"-fashion, the **`tcp://`** does not have this comfort, as it has to first generate all the transport-class specific contracts with O/S, with device-driver(s), instantiate transport-class specific ISO/OSI-{ L0, L1, L3, L3+ }-processing policies, instantiate respective data-pumping code into the `Context()`'s RTO-state, allocate and map memory buffer(s) for serving these purposes, so pretty lot of work to be done, before the **`PUB`**-side gets into the RTO-state, where it ( under newer versions of ~ API 4.+ ) has also the duty to both receive **and** process the subscription service-telemetry, as it bears the concentrated responsibility for per-**`SUB`**-client TOPIC-filterlist processing.

This is **why** it resulted in hanging **`.recv( ..., ZMQ_BLOCK )`** burried inside the NetMQ wrapped abstraction of `subSocket.ReceiveFrameString()`.

To test it, just make the modified test:

```
  // --------------------------------------------------- // DEMO PSEUDO-CODE
     string rF = "";

     while True:
         
           pubSocket.SendFrame( "Hello world!", false ); // keep sending ...
                                                         // also may count++
                                                         // so as to "show" how
                                                         // many loops it took
           rF = subSocket.ReceiveFrameString(   false ); // non-blocking mode ~
                                                         // .recv(  ZMQ_NOBLOCK )
                                                         // or may use Poll()
                                                         // to just sniff for
                                                         // a message presence
           if  rF == "":
               continue; // ---^ LOOP NEXT, AS DID .recv() NOTHING YET
           break; // ----------v BREAK      AS DID .recv() MESSAGE
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Console.WriteLine( rF );
```

One may carry more efforts and experiment here to see, the key roles of both the **`.connect()`**-related overheads but also the need not to miss the **`SUB`**-side signalled telemetry on setting the subscription(s) + the need to receive it + reprocess it on the **`PUB`**-side, before any message gets first ever at all dispatched towards the intended, **otherwise a just "*forever*"-waiting, `SUB`**

---

A "fat"-enough **`.sleep( someGuestimateTIME )`** proposed already by [@HesamFaridmehr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1926477/hesam-faridmehr), after the **`SUB`**-side has both `.connect()`-ed plus it's `.setsockopt( ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE )` ( that has to get first delivered and also processed in a due fashion on the **`PUB`**-side ( to configure the TOPIC-filter list-processor processor properly ) ) **all that well-enough before the first `PUB.send()`** will **mask the root-cause** by making it "indirectly" blocked and the code-execution flow stops, **instead of making the solution smart-enough** - using a non-blocking form of **`Poll()`** for example - for a professional [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) design best-practices, where one can indeed but obey the assembly hackers beloved first line present macro **`#ASSUME NOTHING;`**.

Answer (score 2):

Because `pub/sub` pattern is like radio. Publisher won't wait utill subscriber connects it will ignore sending if there is no subscriber. you can test that just by adding `Thread.Sleep(1000);` after `subSocket.SubscribeToAnyTopic();` line and you will see that you will receive the message.

In `inproc`, time for binding is less than `tcp` that's why your receiving the message

And in `inproc,` publisher should be up before subscriber connects

Comment: That makes sense, and I feel a bit silly now in hindsight.  I had assumed that Connect would block until the connection was actually completed.  I don't really like the idea of just putting a sleep in the tests because, in my experience, whatever number I choose for the sleep will be wrong at least 20% of the time.  I can try to use a monitor to check when the connection has actually be established, I suppose.